# Is there any maximum limit in file size for Huffman compression?

Tags: file, compression, ascii, huffman-code

As far as Huffman compression goes, it can compress any files containing ASCII symbols etc. However, is there any maximum limit on the file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no limit. You can string Huffman codes for as long as you like.